# Error al querer subir un archivo por medio de un formulario

Tags: ajax, php5

alguien me puede explicar que significa este error que me da el servidor.
Muchas gracias y perdonen mi ignorancia.

[Tue Mar 30 18:18:11.054459 2021] [:error] [pid 2689492:tid 140074670593792] [client 181.31.216.148:52147] [client 181.31.216.148] ModSecurity: Multipart parsing error: Multipart: Final boundary missing. [hostname "ciec.com.ar"] [uri "/upload.php"] [unique_id "YGOjhSb82i9PDdJSOKmvXAAAbhU"], referer: https://ciec.com.ar/miciec.php
este es el código que utilizo para hacer el upload del archivo.

upload.php

```
<?php         
$tipo_archivo = $_FILES['myfile']['type'];
$tamano_archivo = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
if (!((strpos($tipo_archivo, "pdf")) && ($tamano_archivo < 33554432))) {
echo "
<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">La extensión o el tamaño 
de los archivos no es correcta. <br>
Se permiten archivos .pdf<br>
se permiten archivos de 32 MB máximo.</div>\n";
}
elseif(!empty($_FILES)) {
include("php/db.php");
include("php/funciones.php");
$fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
$fecha_mail= FormatDateTime($fecha, 2);
$name=$_POST['name'];
$matricula=$_POST['matricula'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];
$obra=$_POST['obra'];
$comitente=$_POST['comitente'];
$observaciones=$_POST['observaciones'];
$celular=$_POST['celular'];
$acepto=$_POST['acepto'];

function random(){ $str="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz234567890";
$cad = "";
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
$cad .= substr($str,rand(0,120),1);
}
return $cad;
}
$userImage = basename($_FILES['myfile']['name']);
$userImage = random().".pdf";
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'])) {
$sourcePath = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = "expediente/".$userImage;
$query = "INSERT INTO expe (archivo, fecha, nombre_expe, matric_expe, 
descripcion_expe, obra_expe, email, celular, comitente_expe, 
observaciones_expe, acepto) VALUES ('$userImage','$fecha','$name','$matricula','$descripcion','$obra','$email','$celular','$comitente','$observaciones','$acepto' )";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
//codigo de envio
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
ini_set('track_errors', true);

function DoStripSlashes($fieldValue)  { 
// temporary fix for PHP6 compatibility - magic quotes deprecated in PHP6
if ( function_exists( 'get_magic_quotes_gpc' ) && get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) 
{ 
if (is_array($fieldValue) ) { 
return array_map('DoStripSlashes', $fieldValue); 
} else { 
return trim(stripslashes($fieldValue)); 
} 
} else { 
return $fieldValue; 
} 
}
function FilterCChars($theString) {
return preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F]/', '', $theString);
}

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
$clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
$clientIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
$FTGname = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['name'] );
$FTGmatricula = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['matricula'] );
$FTGemail = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['email'] );
$FTGfecha = DoStripSlashes( $fecha_mail );

$validationFailed = false;
# Include message in error page and dump it to the browser
if ($validationFailed === true) {
$errorPage = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" 
content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>Error</title></head><body>Se 
han encontrado errores: <!--VALIDATIONERROR--></body></html>';
$errorPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:nombre-->', $FTGname, 
$errorPage);
$errorPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:matricula-->', $FTGmatricula, 
$errorPage);
$errorPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:email-->', $FTGemail, 
$errorPage);
$errorPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:email-->', $FTGfecha, 
$errorPage);
$errorList = @implode("<br />\n", $FTGErrorMessage);
$errorPage = str_replace('<!--VALIDATIONERROR-->', $errorList, 
$errorPage);
echo $errorPage;
}
if ( $validationFailed === false ) {
# Email to Form Owner
$emailSubject = FilterCChars("Confirmación Expedientes Ciec");
$emailBody = "<div style=\"text-align: center; margin-bottom: 10px\"><img 
src=\"https://ciec.com.ar/images/logomiciec.png\" alt=\"logo miciec\"/> 
</div>"
. "<div style=\"text-align: center; margin-bottom: 30px\"><img 
src=\"https://ciec.com.ar/images/linea2.png\" alt=\"linea\"/></div>"
. "Estimada/o <b>$FTGname</b><br>"
. "Su expediente fué cargado con éxito en Nuestro Sistema, con fecha 
<b>$FTGfecha</b><br>"
. "<br>"
. "<b>Colegio de Ingenieros Especialistas de Córdoba</b><br>"
. "Jujuy 441 - Córdoba Capital.<br>"
. "Tel: 0351- 4220081 / 4220046 / 4236074"
. "<br><br>"
. "<div style=\"text-align: center; margin-bottom: 5px\"><img 
src=\"https://ciec.com.ar/images/linea2.png\" alt=\"linea\"/></div>"
. "<div style=\"text-align: center;\">(Este email fué enviado por un 
sistema automático. Por favor no lo respondas)</div><br>" 
. "";
$emailTo = FilterCChars("$FTGemail");
$emailFrom = 'ciec <noreply@ciec.com.ar>';
$emailHeader = "From: noreply@ciec.com.ar\n"
. 'Bcc: alejandro@arla.com.ar' . "\n"
. "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
. "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n"
. "Content-transfer-encoding: 8bit\n";
mail($emailTo, $emailSubject, $emailBody, $emailHeader);
# Include message in the success page and dump it to the browser
$successPage = '';
$successPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:nombre-->', $FTGname, 
$successPage);
$successPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:matricula-->', $FTGmatricula, 
$successPage);
$successPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:email-->', $FTGemail, 
$successPage);
$successPage = str_replace('<!--FIELDVALUE:fecha-->', $FTGfecha, 
$successPage);
echo $successPage;
}
if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
echo"
<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">Expediente Enviado con 
Exito</div>\n";
}
}
}
?>
```

aquí va el código del formulario

```
<form id="contact-form" name="form1" method="post" action="upload.php" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input name="fecha" type="hidden" required="required" value="<? 
php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>" />
            <ul class="mb-5">
              <li>
                    <label>Apellido y Nombre <em>(*)</em></label>
                <input name="name" type="text" disabled="disabled" 
required="required" value="<?php echo $session->userinfo['apellido']; ?> <? 
php echo $session->userinfo['nombre']; ?>" data-checkify="required" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Matrícula <em>(*)</em></label>
                <input name="matricula" type="text" disabled="disabled" 
required="required" value="<?php echo $dni ?>" data-checkify="number" />
                </li>
                <li>
                <label>Email: <em>(*)</em></label>
                <input name="email" type="email" required="required" 
value=""/>
                </li>
                <li>
                <label>Celular: <em>(*)</em></label>
                <input name="celular" type="text" required="required" 
value=""/>
                </li>
                <li>
                <label>Tarea / Descripción: <em>(*)</em></label>
                <input name="descripcion" type="text" required="required" 
value="" />
                </li>
                <li>
                <label>Obra: <em>(*)</em></label>
                <input name="obra" type="text" required="required" value=""/>
                </li>
                <li>
                <label>Comitente:<em>(*)</em></label>
                <input name="comitente" type="text" required="required" 
value="" />
                </li>
              <li>
                <label>Archivo: <em>(*)</em></label>
                <p>Los archivos deben ser enviados en formato pdf y no deben 
superar los 32MB de peso.</p>
                <input name="myfile" type="file" required="required" 
class="demoInputBox" id="myfile" />
                </li>
                <li class="textarea">
                <label>Obsevaciones:</label>
                <textarea name="observaciones" rows="6" cols="60"></textarea>
                </li>
            
                <p>
                  <label for="checkbox" id="1"><strong>He leído y acepto las 
condiciones</strong></label>
                  <input name="acepto" type="checkbox" required="required" 
id="acepto" style="border: none; width: 20px; margin-bottom: 40px" 
value="acepto">
                </p>
                <li class="button">
                <input id="btnSubmit" value="Enviar &raquo;" type="submit" 
class="submit" name="Submit"/>
                </li>
            </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
               <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">No Cierre el 
formulario hasta que no reciba la verificación de que su expediente fué 
enviado con Exito</div>
                    <div id="targetLayer"></div>
                <div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>
                <div id="status"></div>
              </form>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('#contact-form').ajaxForm({
beforeSend: function() {
    status.empty();
    var percentVal = '0%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
},
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
},
success: function() {
    var percentVal = '100%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
},
complete: function(xhr) {
    status.html(xhr.responseText);
}
}); 

})();       
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código del formulario y el código que envías para enviar los datos al servidor? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: No veo ningún elemento `form` en el código que compartes. ¿Cuál es tu formulario?

Comment: Para analizar mejor el tema deberías agregar un poco más de información del log. Fijate si hay una línea que verse sobre el Content-Length, es posible que se esté cortando la request porque el límite es muy bajo y ModSecurity verifica el Multipart y lo encuentra roto.